# Use titles of pages/posts on the url

Tags: php

I use to display pages created on website like
http://www.mywebaddress.com/bids/display.php?id=id
but I want to display pages with title of the page on the url,  sth like this 
http://www.mywebaddress.com/bids/title-of-the-bid/ or 
bids/title-of-the-bid.html

Thanks in advance

Comment: @asprin I need one! LOL. User - you want to look at .htaccess and pretty urls. Google is your friend, but here's a start: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the url of this page.

you can make your url like

```
http://www.mywebaddress.com/bids/1234/title-of-the-bid/
```

where 1234 is the post id you are passing and the next parameter helps you build seo friendly urls.

Also if you want like

```
http://www.mywebaddress.com/bids/title-of-the-bid/
```

Then try making title for posts as unique in the database and you can query via that field to retrieve data. The first option would be better. If you still want to adopt the second approach try to do this with this [article](http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/using-mod-rewrite-to-convert-dynamic-urls-to-seo-friendly-urls) after making titles unique.

For doing the same you will have to write a url rewrite rule with help of apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

This 'll be really helpful, not just for this sample but for any other clean url stuffs.

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function you could use to create the URLs

```
/**
     * Create URL Title
     *
     * Takes a "title" string as input and creates a
     * human-friendly URL string with either a dash
     * or an underscore as the word separator.
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string  the string
     * @param   string  the separator: dash, or underscore
     * @return  string
     */
function urlTitle($str, $separator = 'underscore', $lowercase = TRUE)
    {
        if ($separator == 'dash')
        {
            $search     = '_';
            $replace    = '-';
        }
        else
        {
            $search     = '-';
            $replace    = '_';
        }

        $trans = array(
                '&\#\d+?;'              => '',
                '&\S+?;'                => '',
                '\s+'                   => $replace,
                '[^a-z0-9\-\._]'        => '',
                $replace.'+'            => $replace,
                $replace.'$'            => $replace,
                '^'.$replace            => $replace,
                '\.+$'                  => ''
        );

        $str = strip_tags($str);

        foreach ($trans as $key => $val)
        {
            $str = preg_replace("#".$key."#i", $val, $str);
        }

        if ($lowercase === TRUE)
        {
            $str = strtolower($str);
        }

        return trim(rtrim(stripslashes($str),$replace));
    }
```

This is very similar to the code used in a url helper function in the codeigniter framework.

*How to use?*

```
$title = "Nice way to put it";

echo urlTitle($title);//output: "nice_way_to_put_it"
```

The rest of the customization is up to you but surely this is a good start

Comment: thanks, but I want to use the id from
http://www.mywebaddress.com/bids/1234/title-of-the-bid/ which is 1234.
So, how can I split it to get the ids from the url?

Comment: It's simply a matter of appending the id to the formatted URL string. <code>$url=$id . urlTitle($title);</code> and using <code>$id=preg_replace("@^/?(\d+)/.*$@",'$1',$url);</code> to get the id from the url